# How to disable Keyboard Support for RadComboBox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, telerik, radcombobox

The RadComboBox control in Silverlight has Keyboard Support, listed in this page: [Keyboard Support](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radcombobox-features-keyboard-support.html)

I need the RadComboBox features except the keyboard support. I don't find anything on the web to help me to do that. How can I disable the automatic event?

I have to handle each KeyUp and KeyDown event differently from the default behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That was a silly joke in fact :

The very well documented property `CanKeyboardNavigationSelectItems` ([158 results in Google !](http://www.google.com/search?q=CanKeyboardNavigationSelectItems)) do the trick, with the `IsTextSearchEnabled` set to false (don't ask me why).

[See the ultra complete doc.](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/telerik.windows.controls.input-telerik.windows.controls.radcombobox-cankeyboardnavigationselectitems.html)

```
<telerik:RadComboBox x:Name="RadComboBox"
                     CanKeyboardNavigationSelectItems="False"
                     IsTextSearchEnabled="False">
```